# How do I to make an answer only in the data type that I want in Python?

Tags: python

```
def name_hi(x):
    if type(x)!= <type 'str'> :
        print "Invaild answer,Try again"
    else:
        print "Hello"+ x
name_hi(raw_input("what's your name?"))
```

How do I make sure that the answer I get is a string?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: But `raw_input` always returns a string.  Even if the user entered "1234" that would still be a string.  Sure you don't mean `x.isalpha()` ?

Answer (score 6):

You're looking for this:

```
if type(x) == str:
```

or, better yet:

```
if isinstance(x, str):
```

That said, `raw_input()` will only return a string. It doesn't return anything else.

Since you're trying to check whether the string only contains letters, you should call `isalpha()`:

```
if x.isalpha():
```

To integrate that:

```
def name_hi(x):
    if x.isalpha():
        print "Hello, " + x + "."
    else:
        print "Invalid answer; try again."

name_hi(raw_input("What's your name?"))
```

Comment: what is those  " + x + ".", can i just use print "Hello" + x. and can you use while loop please so it keeps repeating if answer is not letters

Comment: You can read about [string concatenation here](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/introduction.html#strings) and the [`while` keyword here](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/compound_stmts.html?highlight=while#while). They are very versatile tools.

Answer (score 0):

you want isinstance()

```
def check(x)
    return isinstance(x, str)
```

Comment: That's better. I was wondering where you were getting `is_string()`. :P

Comment: sorry!  that's what I had called it in my program... ::blush::

Answer (score 0):

Checking for type is brittle. It's arguably better to just try doing what you want to do and see if it works:

```
def name_hi(x):
    try:
        print "Hello"+ x
    except TypeError:
        print "Invaild answer,Try again"
```

So that:

```
>>> name_hi('steve')
Hellosteve
>>> name_hi(42)
Invaild answer,Try again
```

Comment: @Beast2life - then you want `x.isalpha()`, as @cdarke commented above (added to my answer).